# How inspect a dynamic property of ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, viewbag

Im debugging my app in Visual Studio 2013

I create a dynamic property `result` but when I hover over `ViewBag` dont know where to inspect to see the value of the dynamic property.

[image]

I get stuck in a recursive references.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking the refresh icon in the "Dynamic View" row?

Comment: No I haven't. Didnt understand what that mean. I feel so sorry now :(. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expand the Dynamic View by clicking on the refresh icon, it will enumerate through them and show you the values.